# What is the meaning of Haproxy's sessions info page?

Tags: haproxy, session, stat

I'm using haproxy 1.6.8.

The following information is output on

```
echo "show sess" | nc -U /var/lib/haproxy/stats 


0x1696d40: proto=tcpv4 src=67.55.94.187:51183 fe=adf be=adfback srv=capped ts=08 age=0s calls=4 rq[f=8400a0h,i=0,an=2000h,rx=,wx=,ax=] rp[f=400000h,i=0,an=60000h,rx=59s,wx=,ax=] s0=[7,8h,fd=186,ex=] s1=[7,108h,fd=209,ex=] exp=59s
0x17d4dd0: proto=tcpv4 src=173.239.36.124:19785 fe=adf be=adfback srv=capped2 ts=08 age=0s calls=4 rq[f=8400a0h,i=0,an=2000h,rx=,wx=,ax=] rp[f=400000h,i=0,an=60000h,rx=59s,wx=,ax=] s0=[7,8h,fd=100,ex=] s1=[7,108h,fd=246,ex=] exp=59s
0x16f7fc0: proto=tcpv4 src=67.55.94.183:54971 fe=adf be=adfback srv=capped ts=08 age=0s calls=4 rq[f=8400a0h,i=0,an=2000h,rx=,wx=,ax=] rp[f=400000h,i=0,an=60000h,rx=59s,wx=,ax=] s0=[7,8h,fd=168,ex=] s1=[7,108h,fd=288,ex=] exp=59s
0x1a8b170: proto=tcpv4 src=67.55.94.182:18194 fe=adf be=adfback srv=capped ts=08 age=0s calls=4 rq[f=8400a0h,i=0,an=2000h,rx=,wx=,ax=] rp[f=400000h,i=0,an=60000h,rx=59s,wx=,ax=] s0=[7,8h,fd=45,ex=] s1=[7,108h,fd=299,ex=] exp=59s
```

How can I interpret that data? Is there any docs on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.6/doc/management.txt):

> **show sess**   Dump all known sessions. Avoid doing this on slow
>   connections as this can   be huge. This command is restricted and can
>   only be issued on sockets   configured for levels "operator" or
>   "admin".
>
> **show sess**    Display a lot of internal information about the
>   specified session identifier.   This identifier is the first field at
>   the beginning of the lines in the dumps   of "show sess" (it
>   corresponds to the session pointer). Those information are   useless
>   to most users but may be used by haproxy developers to troubleshoot a 
>   complex bug. The output format is intentionally not documented so that
>   it can   freely evolve depending on demands. You may find a
>   description of all fields   returned in src/dumpstats.c
>
> The special id "all" dumps the states of all sessions, which must be
>   avoided   as much as possible as it is highly CPU intensive and can
>   take a lot of time.